# I want to detect modem outgoing port but my code fails to show me result?

Tags: detection, modem

I want to get Modem outgoing port Through visual basic 6 Mscomm1. I am using Nokia c2 0i for my modem. Code  connect with modem and send message also . My question is how can i get correct  Modem outgoing port and show its name in message box. Please check my code for correction:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
Dim FromModem$
On Error Resume Next
For i% = 1 To 6
MSComm1.CommPort = i%
If MSComm1.PortOpen = False Then
MSComm1.PortOpen = True
MSComm1.InBufferCount = 0
Label8.Caption = " PORT " & i%
pb1.Value = pb1.Value + 10
List2.AddItem i%
Text1.Text = "Searching Modem Port" & i%
MSComm1.Output = "AT" + Chr$(13)
Sleep 4000
If MSComm1.InBufferCount Then
FromModem$ = FromModem$ + MSComm1.Input
If InStr(FromModem$, "OK") Then
MsgBox "Modem has Found" & i%
Beep 400, 300
Timer1.Enabled = False
Exit For
End If
Else
MSComm1.PortOpen = False
End If
End If
DoEvents
Next i%
If i% > 6 Then
Timer1.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you think it is possible to add the identation back in your code? That makes it eaier to consume. And while you're at it try to fix some interpuction and captilization of I and remove the Thanks. That is not needed.

Comment: What doesn't work? Can you connect sucesfully to your modem with other means?

Answer (score 1):

**try this example by using built-in serial port class**
    Imports System
    Imports System.IO.Ports
    Module SerialPortExample

```
    Sub Main()
        Dim ports As String() = SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        Dim port As String 
        For Each port In ports

            'put your function here
        YourTestPort(port) 'Call the Open port function then Send AT(char(13))

        Next port

    End Sub 
End Module
```